# Why does blender look like this?

Tags: workspaces

[image: colourful layout]

I installed the latest version of Blender on my old mac and it looks like this???
Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: it must not work with your system, maybe try a old version of Blender

Comment: the reasons can be diverse, you can ask this in [Developer Blender] (https://developer.blender.org/)